# SharePoint 2013 Online Event Receiver Not Working

Tags: sharepoint-online

I've develop a custom event receiver as a SandBoxed solution, but i always get the error object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Can anyone please tell me if this is possible, or if i'm doing something wrong here?

I'll paste a link to my solution in case that anyone is interested in see it.

[Solution](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=e191dcedb563e50b&id=E191DCEDB563E50B!467)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, I develop on Office 365 and make sandboxed event receivers all the time. I was unable to open your project due to it being incompatible With my VS2012, but thought you would like to know that it is possible all the same.

A suggestion might be to set up a SharePoint server and debug the event handlers there before you create a .wsp and upload it to O365, that is what I do and I can't even begin to imagine how much time I would spend debugging if I did not...